# Using @Schedule in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

Hello i working on a cron job and would like to  schedule the task to run once every two weeks on a Monday morning using @schedule in spring can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You should be more precise with your exact current problem. You know that there is an annotation for that... but what's going on when you use it ? How do you use it ? what version of spring(-boot) ? ...

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the getting started examples in the spring.io website:

[Scheduling Tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

For your use case you'll be using the scheduled annotation with a cron expression:

```
@Scheduled(cron=". . .")
```

This uses the [CronSequenceGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html).

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentioned you just have to add the @Scheduled annotation. however if using spring boot dont forget to add this anotation @EnableScheduling in the main class of your app

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyApplication {
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you use not springboot but spring framework, you can configure scheduling job like below.

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class SchedulingConfig {
 // ...
}
```

And use like this.

```
private static final int TEN_MINUTES = 60 * 10 * 1000;

@Scheduled(fixedRate = TEN_MINUTES)
public void doSomething() {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the cron expression for every two weeks, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46109358/19322223)'re some discussion.

It seems not very convenient to use cron expression to set two weeks schedule. Instead, you can use cron expression to set weekly tasks, and use a boolean variable to flip the boolean value:

```java
boolean flag;

// run the method at 8:00 AM every Monday
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 8 * * MON")
public void schedulingTask() {
    // run the actual task only if flag is true
    if (flag) {
        // handle the biweekly task 
    }
    // flip the flag
    flag = !flag;
}
```